# What is the easiest way to load and play sounds in a java application?

Tags: java, audio

I'm relatively new to java (I took a 1 semester online class, so I know the basic structure of the language but my knowledge has lots of gaps). I'm trying to write a simple ear training application for a class in microtonal music I'm taking, and I obviously need to be able to play sound with this application. Looking on the web, a lot of the info I've found is out of date and I'm having trouble figuring out the APIs for Clip, Dataline, etc. (again, I'm new!) Is there a simple way to load sounds onto some kind of object (like an AudioClip maybe?) so they can be played back when necessary? If it's more complicated than that, I would appreciate being directed to resources that would help me figure how this process works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to play a audio clip using java application

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
    // Clip finishing; see comments.

           public void run() {
              try {
                  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                  AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                  Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
                  clip.open(inputStream);
                  clip.start(); 
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                  }
          }
    }).start();
}
```

Here's another tutorial on java how to add audio clips. You can check this too [Tutorial in playing sounds in Java](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14083-incredibly-easy-way-to-play-sounds/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not quite sure how to use the code though :(. I'll try to be specific about what my confusions are:

Comment: @AlfredBrewer I got your question as, you want to play audio using your java application. If that was the question, then that's the answer :) Don't worry. if any problem, please comment or ask another question.

Comment: First, when I try to compile the code you gave me, I get this error: Error: /Users/Alfred/Sounds.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Main. Second, is the "/path/to/sounds/" a comment on what url is supposed to be, or is it a placeholder for something I need to add? I'm not sure if I'm even asking the right questions, but thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, never mind. I changed the "main" in the code to the name of my class and it compiled :)

Comment: Now that the code is compiled, I tried playing a sound by using the name of the file I want to play as the string parameter in this method, but I got a "null" as an output. Will java automatically find the file on my computer or do I need to load it on somehow?

Comment: what is the JVM version that you are using? Java7?

Comment: @AlfredBrewer well. then inside the class.getResourceAsStream("pass your audio path"));


make a folder called audio, in your root directory and then copy the audio file to that location, then give the path as "/audio.mp3"

that should work.

Comment: I feel really stupid :( I guess I don't really know how to do that. Maybe this project is above my head. I can't figure out how you copy a file to a directory, where I'd make the directory, etc. On a related note, do you know any good online resources for learning the basics of java more solidly? It seems that every time I look something up, I don't know enough about the language to be able to understand the answer.

Comment: @AlfredBrewer don't worry, Learning will make easy to do anything. Please refer the following tutorials. I believe it'd help you. 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the following:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
```

I created a method for playing the audio clip, as shown below:

```
public static void myMusic() throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        File wavFile = new File(/*file path*/);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile));
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Let's say for example, if your audio clip's file name is **music.wav**, your file path may be:

```
File wavFile = new File("music.wav");
```

Finally, to play the audio clip, you will need to call the method.